# SQL server slowing down, what could be the reason/ways to improve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a set of 30 files. I loop through these files and for each one I insert 1529 rows which have approximately 30 columns, and 219487 rows which contain approximately 6 columns.

I am doing this in C# and I insert via a datatable (see bottom). I have grouped the insertions into 1,300 rows per batch for the 1529 rows (30 columns) and 50000 per batch for the 219,487 rows (6 columns).

When inserting each batch, there is no multithreading- everything is sequential (at least in my code). I dont start on the next file until my line of code has completed inserting the previous file.

With this in mind, I would expect the SQL server to complete each file in a constant time (the files are very similar, it is always 1529 and 219487 insertions).

However, the time taken for each SQL insertion per file increases linearly- from 9 seconds on the first file, to 50 seconds towards the 30th file. I have separated the CPU time from the SQL time taken and at the beginning it is taking 0.000033 seconds to insert one of the 6-column rows. Towards the end, for the later files, for the 6-column data, the time taken is 0.000228. In other words, the time taken to insert the 219,487 row (6 column) data has increased by about 7 times?

I decreased the batch size to 20000 and it made no difference. In the past I believe I reduced it to 5000 and 10000 and it still made no difference. I do not know a great deal about the underlying SQL architecture so I am a little lost.

It feels to me that I am overloading the SQL server. However, is was under the impression this was being done sequentially rather than giving jobs to the SQL server? Its possible the SQL requests are spawned via threads, however I reduce the batch size to 100 (see further below) and this still didnt help. The overall time to complete was longer, but it still increased linearly per file.

I have reduced the batch size to 100 (just to ensure the server isn't being overloaded) and I am still seeing linearly increasing times??

Throughout I have been referring to the time taken for SQL insertion, not the combined SQL + CPU time per file.

It'll probably be impossible to advise EXACTLY what is happening, but could I have some tips and things to definitely avoid to best possibly fix this?

My SQL insertion code (called per each batch insertion) is:

```
private static void WriteResultsToDatabase(string tableName, DataTable tableToWrite)
        {

            using (SqlConnection connection =
                    new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                    new SqlBulkCopy
                    (
                    connection,
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers |
                    SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction,
                    null
                    );

                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                for (int i = 0; i < tableToWrite.Columns.Count; i++)
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(tableToWrite.Columns[i].ColumnName, tableToWrite.Columns[i].ColumnName);
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(tableToWrite);

                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> It feels to me that I am overloading the SQL server

Yes, that is a good reason - especially and only if your sql server runs on a mobile phone or has a pathetic end user disc. Otherwise - no.

> I do not know a great deal about the underlying SQL architecture so I am a little lost.

Find out. Get the query plans. Table + indices are needed. Unique constraints? Is there a unique constraint WITHOUT index? That forces a table scan all the time.

Also worth: Insert into a temporary table you create from the original table (trivial) then copy the data over in one statement.

> from 9 seconds on the first file

For 220.000 rows that is plenty already. I suggest checking the server how busy it is during your poerations and all constraints on the table for matching indices. And triggers ;)

Comment: Get the query plan for a simple insert statement?

Comment: Actually - no. But if there are triggers they show up in the executed plan, you know. It may LOOK like a simple insert but trigger a ton of processing. Unique constraints triggering a select etc.

Comment: When I said SQL architecture I meant how SQL works under the hood- not a particular query plan :)

Comment: There are no triggers (not that I have specifically added anyway). The only constraints are a foreign key which relates the table consisting of 6 columns to the table with 30 columns. I have not added any specific indexes, only a primary key on both tables.

Comment: THat ould be it. Check whether foreign key constraints are properly inddexed.

Answer (score 0):

This could be any number of things, but the obvious ones to me would be as follows:

1. You have a clustered key on the tables, and you are not inserting
   the records in the order of that key.  For every insert operation,
   it will need to physically reorder the records before completing the
   task.
2. You have multiple indexes/ foreign keys with checks on the tables,
   so with every iteration you are adding more and more information to
   check against.
3. Your triggers are not efficiently being used, or are not constructed
   efficiently, to the point that it needs to work against the entire
   table instead of the recently inserted data.
4. You have set up a bulk transaction, but something is preventing the
   database server from treating it like one.  Make sure the activity
   monitor sees this as a bulk operation.
5. You are autogrowing your database by percentage instead of by a
   fixed amount; for each grow it  will take longer to allocate more
   space.

These are all problems I have experienced before; any one of them or any combination could create the symptoms you are describing.